# jQuery $() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery so I am wondering what does

```
$('#someid a')
```

referring to?

and when does the function $.get get called? (since I feel the code after $.get is called before $.get

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It selects the exact same element(s) as it would in CSS.

Comment: Why are you asking about `$.get` when it is not in your sample code?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#someid a')
```

Selects all `a` tags contained within an element with the id `someid`

I don't see any calls to `$.get`, so I don't understand that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It creates (selects (it's a selector))  a new jQuery object which holds `a` tag in #someid

```
$.get
```

is called to call a page with ajax

Answer (score 0):

`$("#someid a")` will select all `<a>` tags that are inside of the first element that has an id of `#someid`.

`$.get()` makes an asynchronous http request to the given url. once the request returns, the callback is ran.

i suggest going through the jquery getting started tutorials

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Selects zero or more 'a' tags contained by a tag with id "someid". $.get is called when the execution gets to the line containing $.get. See the documentation for more information about $.get here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/